# Computer Science Theory: Image Similarity

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, theory

So I'm trying to run a comparison of different images and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for some basic metrics I can take for the group of images.

Assuming I have two images, A and B, I pretty much want as much data as possible about each so I can later programmatically compare them. Things like "general color", "general shape", etc. would be great.

If you can help me find specific properties and algorithms to compute them that would be great!

Thanks!

EDIT: The end goal here is to be able to have a computer tell me how "similar" too pictures are. If two images are the same but in one someone blurred out a face; they should register as fairly similar. If two pictures are completely different, the computer should be able to tell.

Comment: Do they have to be exactly the same or you want to compute a "distance" between them? (note that *Metric* means distance, and takes two parameters, while *general color* is qualifier, that takes one parameter).

Comment: Be prepared that whatever algorithm you'll choose to use, the result will feel disappointing. The human brain is so much more efficient at this task than any computer is at the moment, that you'll inevitably find lots of false positives and negatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about is way much general and non-specific.

Image information is formalised as [Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

What you seem to be looking for is basically feature extraction and then comparing these features. There are tons of features that can be extracted but a lot of them could be irrelevant depending on the differences in the pictures.

There are space domain and [frequency domain descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain) of the image which each can be useful here. I can probably name more than 100 descriptors but in your case, only one could be sufficient or none could be useful.

Pre-processing is also important, perhaps you could turn your images to grey-scale and then compare them.

**This field is so immensely diverse, so you need to be a bit more specific.**

### (Update)

What you are looking for is a topic of hundreds if not thousands of scientific articles. But well, perhaps a simplistic approach can work.

So assuming that the question here is **not identifying objects** and there is no **transform, translation, scale or rotation** involved and we are only dealing with the two images which are the same but one could have more noise added upon it:

1) Image domain (space domain): Compare the pixels one by one and add up the square of the differences. Normalise this value by the width*height - just divide by the number of pixels. This could be a useful measure of similarity.

2) Frequency domain: Convert the image to frequency domain image (using FTT in an image processing tool such as OpenCV) which will be 2D as well. Do the same above squared diff as above, but perhaps you want to limit the frequencies. Then normalise by the number of pixels. This fares better on noise and translation and on a small rotation but not on scale.

Comment: Thanks Aliostad; I was so general because I'm honestly not all too sure what to look for right now. I've edited the question to explain my end goal a little better

Comment: @djs22: it depends on what modifications you want to be able to catch. Shift? Crop? Mirror? Scale? Lossy recompression? Gamma correction? Change of luminance?

Comment: @ruslik: I know this is bold but the answer is everything. Most important would be to see if someone has modified the actual image content ie colors, crops, etc. 

Compression/mirroring doesn't change the content and thus is irrelevant to me.

Comment: @djs22: Then you'll need strong AI algorithms. Maybe you are looking for Fractal compression :)

Answer (score 1):

**SURF is a good candidate algorithm for comparing images**

[Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF)

A practical example (in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)), identifying corresponding points in two images of the moon (rotated, colorized and blurred) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also calculate sum of differences between histogram bins of those two images. But it is also not a silver bullet...

Comment: This requires both images. The question was about what information can be computed from an image, and used later for comparison.

Comment: @ruslik
Is it hard to pre-compute histograms of images and store them as 256 byte array ? (OP doesn't said anything about image signature storage requirements)

Comment: Also, it will not catch crop, lossy recompression or croma/luminance change.

Comment: @ruslik,
I find it very natural that currently doesn't exist any signature method which could catch all possible transformations to image.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).  The package offers most (if not all) of the techniques mentioned above.